# How to count P & A in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please help someone!

I have a table `View_SMS_Mark_Attendance` which contains columns like

```
[Class] | [S_Adm_No] |  [Alias], | [DateTime]
```

My question is how can I count P and A separately like.

```
Class | S_Adm_NO | Month | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | Total_P  | Total_A 
Nur-A | 1101     | April | A | P | P | P | P | A | A |  4       | 3
Nur-A | 1102     | April | P | P | P | P | P | A | A |  5       | 2
Nur-A | 1103     | April | A | P | A | P | P | A | A |  3       | 4
```

To get my result I am using a SQL query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         [Class], [S_Adm_No], [Alias],
         DATENAME(M, [DateTime])as [Month],
         DAY([DateTime]) as [DayValue] 
     FROM   
         [View_SMS_Mark_Attendance]) AS Composite 
     PIVOT 
         (MAX([Alias])
            FOR [DayValue] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4],[5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13],[14],[15],[16], [17], [18], [19],
                               [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31])) AS pt 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
         [Class], [S_Adm_No], 
         SUM(CASE WHEN [Alias] = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfP, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN [Alias] = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SumOfA
     FROM  
         [View_SMS_Mark_Attendance]  
     GROUP BY 
         [Class], [S_Adm_No]) AS at ON pt.[Class] = at.[Class] 
                                    AND pt.[S_Adm_No] = at.[S_Adm_No]
```

I want to get result only particular month and class by using 'WHERE month & class'

Please help someone!

Comment: You managed to get the complicated part working. Why are you struggling with a where clause?

Comment: Can you post sample input so that I can try on my sql server ?

Comment: This is values
[Class] | [S_Adm_No] |  [Alias], | [DateTime]
Nur -A |  1101             | P           | 2017-04-01
Nur -A |  1101             | A           | 2017-04-02
Nur -A |  1101             | P           | 2017-04-03

Answer (score 1):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT [Class], [S_Adm_No], [Alias], DATENAME(MONTH, [DateTime]) as [Month],
       MAX(CASE WHEN DAY([DateTime]) = 1 THEN Alias END) as [1],
       MAX(CASE WHEN DAY([DateTime]) = 2 THEN Alias END) as [2],
       . . .,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DayValue = 31 THEN Alias END) as [31],
       SUM(CASE WHEN Alias = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NumPs,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Alias = 'P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as NumAs,
FROM View_SMS_Mark_Attendance
GROUP BY [Class], [S_Adm_No], [Alias], DATENAME(MONTH, [DateTime]);
```

Comment: Error occurred invalid column name DayValue